# How to rotate array

Tags: go

I'm trying to solve this problem from HackerEarth.
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/codemonk/

It is basically a problem of rotating array.
I've got my answer correct for most the test cases, except for Input #5.
It says that time limit exceeded.
I'm using golang to solve it.
I've tried similar method using C++ & there is no such problem. Does anybody know how to solve this in golang?

Below is my code:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var T int

    fmt.Scan(&T)

    for T>0 {
        var N, K int
        fmt.Scan(&N)
        var arr = make([]string, N)

        fmt.Scan(&K)
        for i:=0; i<N; i++ {
            fmt.Scan(&arr[i])
        }

        K = K%N
        for i:=0; i<N; i++ {
            offset := (i + (N-K)) % N
            fmt.Printf("%s ", arr[offset])
        }

        fmt.Println()
        T -= 1
    }
}
```

And this is the result of my submission:
[image]

Comment: You didn't show the problem statement. Furthermore, timing on these sites tends to be really iffy.

Comment: Hi, sorry the problem is quite length thats' why I gave the link instead. Basically I need to rotate array arr of length N, with K steps of rotation. Example arr = [1 2 3 4 5], K=2 ==> the output should be [4 5 1 2 3]. In my above code there's additional variable T denoting no of test cases

Comment: instead of creating a new string array every input, you might want to try initializing it once with size of max N, then reuse the array for all inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stdin and Stdout are not buffered by default in go, and `fmt.Scan` is likely to read from Stdin a character at a time, resulting in a large amount of inefficiency. A version of your code using `bufio.NewReader` runs vastly faster on my machine (although I'm using WSL which does not have great io performance).

If that's not fast enough, the next thing to try is to buffer output instead of writing directly to os.Stdout.

```
package main

import (
        "bufio"
        "fmt"
        "os"
)

func main() {
        var T int
        in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Fscan(in, &T)

        for T > 0 {
                var N, K int
                fmt.Fscan(in, &N)
                var arr = make([]string, N)

                fmt.Fscan(in, &K)
                fmt.Println(T, N, K)
                for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
                        fmt.Fscan(in, &arr[i])
                }

                K = K % N
                for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
                        offset := (i + (N - K)) % N
                        fmt.Printf("%s ", arr[offset])
                }

                fmt.Println()
                T -= 1
        }
}
```